# Do Git and TFS Play Well Together?

Tags: git, tfs

I tried to do a git init on a directory under TFS control - and no .git files were created.  When I tried again to do a git init - it recognized I had already tried - but still no gitattributes or gitignore files.  Do Git and TFS work on the same directories?

Comment: With `git init` command only a `.git` folder will be created - no `.gitignore` nor `.gitattributes`. See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

Answer (score 0):

`git init` doesn't add any files by default, it just initializes a git repo locally (adds a hidden `.git` folder to track git data in. You'll need to add these files manually.

With regards to "in TFS", if you mean TFVC, I don't recommend mixing TFVC and git in the same working folders. It throws off Visual Studio considerably. Though you can probably get it to work from the commandline if you exclude `tf$/` in git and ignore `.git/` in TFVC.

Answer (score 0):

https://wadevelop.blogspot.com/2023/11/how-to-use-tfs-git-at-same-folder.html

**Let .git just a path.**

Example: Use GitBash on Window.
TFS folder: `C:/Users/YouName/AppData/Local/Temp/test/source1/`
cat .git
`gitdir: C:/Users/YouName/AppData/Local/Temp/test/source_git_repo`

Before open VistualStudio TFS. **Rename .git to .git-repo**
VS will no warning. and work correct.

Before use GIT. **Rename .git-repo to .git**